# Awk/Grep - Pull Value from row and replace if it matches File data [Find->Compare->Replace]

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

I have a file with long rows and a file with reference data. **Flong**, **Fref**.

My goal is to search specific field(s) from **Flong** rows compare them to all values from **Fref** and replace them with the given value if they match.

Basically search file **Flong** - row 1 - field 4 against **Fref** - all rows - field 1.
If it matches check field 6 against field 2, if that matches replace field 4 with field 3. If 1 or 2 don't match then ignore it, make no changes.

**Flong** contains data like:

```
Name|location|111|22|333|4444| |6666||8
Name|location| |56|67|| |6666||8
```

Some fields are empty and some have spaces but all are separated by '|'

**Fref** contains data like:

```
574|5327|1000
22|4444|2000
67|77|3000
```

RETURN:

```
Name|location|111|2000|333|4444| |6666||8
Name|location| |56|67|| |6666||8
```

I know this is do-able with a function but I have been shocked by the complexity people can work into Awk so I have been trying to use that but any string search/editor is usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stated `RETURN`, what you appear to want to do is construct a hash (associative array) keyed on fields 1 and 2 of `Fref`, and then use fields 4 and 6 of `Flong` as a lookup key:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    BEGIN{OFS = FS} 
    NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
    $4 FS $6 in a {$4 = a[$4 FS $6]} 
    1
' Fref Flong
Name|location|111|2000|333|4444| |6666||8
Name|location| |56|67|| |6666||8
```

Comment: That is a great solution. 
Could you explain the OFS=FS part?

Comment: @Gray_M `OFS=FS` just sets the output field separator to be the same as the input field separator (i.e. `|`, as given by the `-F` command line argument)