# Using Variable Int as positional arg [$($var) instead of $6]

Tags: awk

I was working on an awk function to handle file translation and I did not expect to run into an issue with substitution.

Current code:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    BEGIN{OFS = FS} 
    NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
    $8 FS $9 in a {$8 = a[$8 FS $9]} 
    1' File1 File2
```

So File1 is generated by me and will always only have 3 fields.
But File2 can be one of several files, each of which would use a different argument number to access its data.

File2.a may have 20 arguments where arg 8 and 9 are the target values

File2.b may have 200 args where 4 and 159 are the target values

How can i handle this variability?
I have tried 
${$var}, ${!var}, `echo $var`, eval
none of it seems to work

Desired code:

```
NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
    ${$var1} FS ${$var2} in a {${$var1} = a[${$var1} FS ${$var2}]} 

[Where var1 and var2 acts as parameter args for File2]
[var1 = ${16} and var2 = ${25}]
```

Additionally: Is there a limit to the number of parameter args that can be recognized? I've had conflicting responses. Like $9 is max, ${19} is max, 255, there is no limit its based off system specs...ect

**Edit:** I will attempt to clarify my question as best I can as requested in comments
I am using awk to compare and replace arguments in a file. File1 will always have 3 arguments, The first 2 will correlate to args from File2.
File2 will have an undetermined number of arguments. The mapping of the args between file1 and 2 will be handled by variable. As such I am trying to use a variable ($var1) in awk as a positional argument.

If I use:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    BEGIN{OFS = FS} 
    NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
    $8 FS $9 in a {$8 = a[$8 FS $9]} 
    1' File1 File2
```

My code works.

If I use:

```
var1=9
$ awk -F'|' '
    BEGIN{OFS = FS} 
    NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
    $8 FS $var1 in a {$8 = a[$8 FS $var1]} 
    1' File1 File2
```

It no longer works

I have tried replacing $9 (in the awk) with ${$var1} / $(!var1) / $$var1

None of these have worked as expected
For file architect please see my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544068/awk-grep-pull-value-from-row-and-replace-if-it-matches-file-data-find-compar)

Comment: `awk` has `-v` option: `awk -v var1=8 -v var2=9 ...`, maybe it helps, hard tot tell as you're question is a bit confusing. Especially the part where you seem to mix `bash` and `awk`.

Comment: `awk` can't guess how to instance `$var1` Maybe use `NR==FNR` clause to setup var1 and var2. (e.g. var1=$1, var2=$2 ... )

Comment: I considered this but both of these suggestions rely on using the positional arg to make a variable. The issue I have is that I only need 2-3 variable but the possible positional args can be as high as 200. My goal is to choose the position based off of variable so that I wouldnt need to create 200 vars just to check arg ${200}

Comment: My unix/bash terminology is weak, my apologies if I misname things.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but `awk -v k=1 '{print $k}'` will print the 1st field, `awk -v k=2 '{print $(k+3)}'` will print the 5th field, etc. The syntax is just `$variable_name` or `$expression`, with the `$` operator binding pretty tight.

Comment: `$` in awk is an _operator_, it's not a magic sigil which introduce a macro/var/substitution like in `bash`, `perl`, `make`, etc. `${whatever}` is a syntax error, but you can stack `$` operators: `echo 2 3 4 5 6 | awk -v k=2 '{print $$$$k}'`

Comment: `mawk` (the default `awk` in debian) seems to be limited to 32767 fields. `gawk` and the updated version of the original awk don't seem to have any hard limit to the number of fields.

Comment: What is the problem with `$$8`? Try: `echo 19 {b..z} | awk '{print $1,$$1}'`

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. In particular it SOUNDS like you simply need a solution that identifies fields from a leading header line so make sure to include that if present. wrt `$9 is max, ${19} is max`, etc. - you're talking about shell there, not awk. awk and shell are completely different tools. You can call awk from shell just like you can call any other executable written in any other language from shell, that's all.

Comment: What happens to your non-working **added** code if you try: `var1=9;awk -F'|' -v var1=$var1'BEGIN{OFS = FS}; NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next}; $8 FS $var1 in a {$8 = a[$8 FS $var1]}; 1' File1 File2` now.

Comment: @Isaac My original test using -v must have fails for a different reason. Upon retrying it I see that is does work. My confusion made it harder to understand the advice of pLumo and mosvy. Thanks to you three and all who gave me a clearer understanding of awk.
I had not considered that bash $var and awk $var would be treated differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To leave the answer for future searchers. Provided by pLumo and other commenters.

awk and bash treat '$' differently. You can use `awk -v $var1=$input`

-v is used to create variables. $var1 is the awk variable name. $input is the bash variable name. As mentioned by Issac they can even have the same names

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that the symbol `$` has different effects and meaning for the shell (e.g. bash) and for `awk`.

In the shell, `${name}` introduces a variable expansion, and when that variable is an integer number, the variable accessed is the list of shell **arguments**. In the shell (bash), the biggest argument (without `{…}`) is `$9`, but with `{…}` there is no (set) limit as long as the new memory requests are granted.

In `awk` the `$` is an operator to access the **fields** of an input line. There is a hard limit at 32767 possible fields in mawk:

```
$ echo $(seq 80000) | mawk '{print $(32767+2)}'
mawk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
```

But not in GNU awk:

```
$ echo $(seq 80000) | awk '{print $(32767+2)}'
32769
```

---

In `awk`, the `$` **operator** could be repeated (as `!` (and some other) could):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{var=111;print( !!!!!!var )}'
1

$ echo 23 {a..z} | awk '{field=1;print( $$field )}'
v
```

Is this closer to what you need?

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
     $$indexa FS $$indexb in a {$$indexa = a[$$indexa FS $$indexb]}
    ' filea indexa=16 indexb=25 fileb
```